# React Typescript context, how to pass an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2pqpta?file=TodoProvider.tsx)

I'm trying to create a simple todo app in React with Typescript using context

I have a context and I'm trying to pass an object in this context to use in other components

```
import React from 'react'
import { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactChildren, ReactChild } from "react";

interface AuxProps {
    children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
  }

  const defaultContext = {
    todoList: ['todo', 'another todo'],
    getNumberTodo: () => void
  }

const TodoContext = createContext<{ todoList: string[], getNumberTodo: () => void }>(defaultContext)

const TodoProvider = ({children}:AuxProps) => {

    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<string[]>(defaultContext.todoList)

    const getNumberTodo = () => todoList.length

    const contextValue = {
        todoList,
        getNumberTodo
    }

    return(
        <TodoContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useTodoContext = () => useContext(TodoContext)

export default TodoProvider
```

I'm trying to create a `defaultContext` to pass to the createContext but I get an error simple saying

```
Expression expected.(1109)
```

Is is possible to pass an object with createContext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void` is an operator. It evaluates its operand on the right and returns undefined.

```
getNumberTodo: () => void
```

That's why it's expecting an expression.

If it's not implemented yet, either implement the function or throw an error that says its not implemented.

Temporary solution: add a 0:

```
getNumberTodo: () => void 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you provided the 'type' of the getNumberTodo (function that returns void) for the value of the defaultContext object. You must provide an actual function:

```
  const defaultContext = {
    todoList: ['todo', 'another todo'],
    getNumberTodo: () => {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@youdateme is correct in explaining the error, but it seems like you don't want that `void` at all.

The type declaration for the context says that `getNumberTodo` is a function which returns `void`.  However in your implementation `const getNumberTodo = () => todoList.length` you are returning a `number`.

I suspect that you are actually intending for `getNumberTodo` to return `number`, not `void`.

You can change the type of your context:

```
const TodoContext = createContext<{ todoList: string[], getNumberTodo: () => number }>(defaultContext)
```

And change the initial value to return a number:

```
const defaultContext = {
  todoList: ['todo', 'another todo'],
  getNumberTodo: () => 2
}
```